# What is the meaning of "Tapestry" title for ST:TNG 6x15 episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I have just watched "[Tapestry](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tapestry_(episode))" episode of Star Trek The Next Generation (6x15) and I have no clue, why such title was chosen for this episode? Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is a reference to greek mythology. The history and fate of humans was represented as a tapestry woven by the gods, with different threads representing different events/people.

Q offers to Picard to change his past (his tapestry). That is where the name comes from.

Quoting from the episode:

> There are many parts of my youth that I'm not proud of. There were... loose threads - untidy parts of me that I would like to remove. But when I... pulled on one of those threads - it unraveled the tapestry of my life.

Comment: It's actually explained in the episode. "There are many parts of my youth that I'm not proud of. There were... loose threads - untidy parts of me that I would like to remove. But when I... pulled on one of those threads - it unraveled the tapestry of my life."